# Custom CMS page not showing in specied pages list of widget page in Admin - Magento 2.2.4

Tags: widgets, cms-pages

Hi I want to add a widget in my custom CMS page, but my custom page is not coming in list of specified pages dowpdown under layout updates in widgets page.

Comment: In Which Version of Magento can You let know?

Comment: In Magento 2.2.4

Comment: bro any solution u got ?